# pexpect.read() throwing a tiimeout

Tags: python, python-3.x, pexpect

So the docs clearly say that it returns an empty string if there is not data:
"This reads at most “size” bytes from the file (less if the read hits EOF before obtaining size bytes). If the size argument is negative or omitted, read all data until EOF is reached. The bytes are returned as a string object. An empty string is returned when EOF is encountered immediately."

```
client = pexpect.spawn(constr,timeout=mytimeout)
client.read()
pexpect.exceptions.TIMEOUT: Timeout exceeded
```

what am I missing, this clearly contradicts the docs?

Comment: I guess it is because you pass a timeout to `spawn()` and there is no data to read before the timeout occurs. From the doc comment of `spawn`: *When the keyword argument ``timeout`` is specified as a number,
        (default: *30*), then :class:`TIMEOUT` will be raised after the value
        specified has elapsed*.

Comment: It depends on what you are running. It may be prompting for data.

Comment: but shouldn't .read always return instantly no matter what?

Comment: No, if the passed size is negative it would wait until `EOF`. Internally it is calling `self.expect(self.delimiter)` when the passed size is negative (default is -1). And self.delimiter is `EOF`. So it would wait until the process has finished.